# Should I create an interface to unify the way the endpoints forms and outputs the response in an API?

Tags: php, api, interface, lumen

So, I'm building an API architecture and I am struck on the way the programmer will be implementing the output of the API endpoints.

The thing is that there can be different ways to store the response that I'm going to output and I'dont know if it would be worth to make an interface and force the developer to use just one way.

**First case**, using a class property.

We have a controller that makes a number of actions all based on a resource 'user' and then in a response handler function returns the formed response:

```
class LogInController implements ResponseInterface{
    private $user;
    private function setUser(){...};
    private function checkThatToTheUser();{...}
    function LogInEndpoint(){
        $this->setUser();
        $this->checkThatToTheUser();
        return $this->handledResponse();
    }
    /**implemented function that doesn't
    take parameters as it has access
    to the class property that has the response formed*/
    function handledResponse(){
        $response = [
            'user_id' => $this->user->id
        ];
        return $this->APIResponse($response);
    };
}
```

**Second case**, directly calling to the response manager.

We have a controller that simply outputs some data from the database, which in this cases can be a collection or a collection of collections.

```
class UserController{
    function get(){
        $users = User::paginate(20);
        return $this->APIReponse($users);
    }
    function getByID($id){
        $user = User::find($id);
        return $this->APIReponse($user);
    }
}
```

**Third case**, we encapsulate all the response generation on a function but having no properties.

In this case we pass the instanciated user to the response handler.

```
class UserActionsController{
    private function get(){
        $user = User::find(1);
        return $user
    }
    private function getComplexThings($user){
        ...
        return $user;
    }
    function getComplextDataEndpoint(){
        $user = $this->get();
        $user = $this->getComplexThings($user);
        return $this->handledResponse($user);
    }
    function handledResponse($user){
        ...
        return $this->APIResponse($user);
    }
}
```

Should I let this open and let the programmer choose in the moment of the implementation or force the way it gets implemented (properties, parameters, directly outputs, outputs under a response handler...).